# Biblatex-philosophy incompatibilities

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing a document with:

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Any two references of same author.

I cannot determine why there is a problem, with another package or some code. The first date after a new author block is not aligned with subsequent dates.

Any idea how to fix this, even by hand, once biber has done its work?

A MWE is included below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, backend=biber, ]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @book{key,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des zweiten Bandes},
    volume = {2},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {muster, etwas},
}
@book{keya,
    author = {Max Muster},
    maintitle = {Der Werktitel},
    title = {Titel des Dritten Bandes},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
}
@book{other,
    author = {Michael Karomann},
    maintitle = {Etwas},
    title = {Nichts},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2002},
    keywords = {test, etwas},
}
@book{other2,
    author = {Michael Karomann},
    maintitle = {Etwas},
    title = {Nichts},
    volume = {3},
    location = {Ort},
    year = {2008},
    keywords = {test, etwas},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks ok to me, I get this result https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efpul.png with a current texlive.

Comment: Surely the MWE should have `\documentclass{amsart}` and not `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: The image given by Ulrike shows the problem, and this is the same with amsart which I use!

Comment: Moreover, @moewe when passing from article to amsart the problem is slightly different, since it occurs event for the second author with amsart.

Comment: I can see a weird effect with `amsart`. But when I use `article` I get the output posted by Ulrike, which looks fine to me. Can you please explain exactly what is wrong with that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an odd effect with `amsart` where the first entry under each name heading would receive additional indentation. This is caused by the `\listparindent` setting of that class and can be countered by setting that length to zero in the bibliography environment definition.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-modern,]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,
    sigfridsson,worman}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Uniformly indented entries]

If there are several entries by the same group of authors from the same year, `biblatex` adds letters to those years. This causes the relevant citation labels to become longer than usual. Because the style aligns all citation labels to the right (this achieves a uniform distance to the beginning of the entry) that means that the years don't line up on the left. If you prefer left-aligned years, you may want to try the following redefinition. (You can tweak the value `1.6em`.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-modern,]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewcommand*{\postsepyear}[1]{%
  \printtext{%
    \makebox[\bibhang][l]{%
    \hspace{1.6em}#1}}\nopunct}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,
    sigfridsson,worman}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: left-aligned years]

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works fine!

Comment: And the problem was the same with article: the firs titles were not aligned with the second enty!